# windows automation and voice control using wake word

Tags: batch-file, winapi, automation, voice-recognition, voice

I want to use a "wake word" with my windows 10 computer, instead of a hotkey, to run a custom windows automation command.

How can I setup windows to use a "wake word" and then run a custom command?

(Also how can I easily make a windows automation script to launch a program, or find the launched program, and send some keyboard keys and maybe mouse clicks?)

Answer (score 1):

welcome! so it sounds like you want to do 3 things, so it should be 3 questions. If you edit these into 3 separate posts, then you might already find the answers, also. without needing to post. I guess the secret is to break down your complex problem into smaller problems first and try for yourself first. Then share what you tried.

OK, I break it down for you here:

1. Use voice control on windows (using cortana) with a "wake word" instead of hardware input device
   https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/enable-hey-cortana-windows-10
2. Make a voice command run a custom Command (using cortana)
   https://www.windowscentral.com/how-run-custom-commands-using-cortana-windows-10
3. you want to easily send keyboard and mouse commands by executing one custom command, check out these options as a sample
   https://windowsreport.com/automate-pc-tasks/

Have a nice day, and you are not too far off from really getting the true benefits out of this site. Also if you break your questions down correctly, you will get upvotes and good reputation instead of a downvote from the people who check your question to see if its ok for use with this site. If you fix your question the downvote will be fixed by whoever did it, too.